# How can i send notification to the users's Gmail Accounts from my Angular 5 App?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular5, gmail-api

I'm working with angular5 as front end and spring-boot as back-end, I want to send notification  from my app angular to users in their gmail accounts .

Can any one here tell me what to use , any helpful links or any idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should never try to send emails from the client side with Angular or any other JS framework) . Anyone can see the source code in the browser. That includes the email settings and credentials. Instead, you should be sending emails from your backend, and Angular app should be just instructing backend when to do that and whom to send.

Comment: Aah i didn't think about that , thank you so much for your answer , i'll do it then with back end :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This abstraction Spring provides on sending emails may be useful. This guide here covers it well.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

You will have to create an email account for your application which will send out the emails. You can use spring to set it up like this

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
mailSender.setPort(587);

mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
mailSender.setPassword("password");
```

Once you have dealt with storing users gmail credentials you can then pass it through to Spring email with a template to provide your notifications. Passing the users email into a template is easy, you can do it like this using Spring

```
SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
        message.setTo(to); 
        message.setSubject(subject); 
        message.setText(text);
        emailSender.send(message);
```

Perhaps look into Apache Velocity for the templates?

Comment: what about angular ? cant we do the same in angular ? and thank you for your answer :) .

Comment: I don't think it is possible to send an email directly with Javascript/Angular. You would use Angular to send off a REST request to a spring endpoint that would then handle sending the email as is demonstrated above.

Comment: Thank you for your help , so i'm going to reaf this article and implement this by the end :) .